# Is it possible to collect both the tweet and user creation date (created_at) from Twitter API?

Tags: python, sql, api, twitter

I'm trying to follow [this](https://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/how-to-extract-twitter-data-with-a-windows-service-created-with-python-in-visual-studio-2017/) tutorial to collect twitter data to a T-SQL database. I've noticed that I only seem to be able to collect the creation date of the user or the tweet, but not both. I was wondering if it would be possible to collect both. In theory, this is the format to collect both:

```
tData['created_at'].append(t['user']['created_at'])
tData['created_at'].append(t['created_at'])
```

I've tried a number of variations of renaming the columns, but I get either ValueError: arrays must all be same length or KeyError: 'created_att'. There's still some parts of the code I don't completely understand, but I was wondering if it's possible to collect both dates without significantly changing the format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'd need two values in tData to hold the two different creation dates. In principle (I've not tested this) it should be something like this:

```
def AddTwittsToDB(twitts):
    tData = {'id': [], 
             'text': [], 
             'screen_name': [],
             'user_created_at': [],  
             'tweet_created_at': [],
             'retweet_count': [], 
             'favorite_count': [],
             'friends_count': [], 
             'followers_count': [], 
             'lang':[], 
             'country':[], 
             'latitude':[], 
             'longitude':[]}
    
    for t in twitts:
        tData['id'].append(t['id'])
        tData['text'].append(t['text'])
        tData['screen_name'].append(t['user']['screen_name'])
        tData['user_created_at'].append(t['user']['created_at'])
        tData['tweet_created_at'].append(t['created_at'])
...
```

Comment: Hey @Andypiper, thanks for trying. I usually get a Invalid column name when I try differentiating by name: Invalid column name 'user_created_at'., but I think I'll have to look into SQLAlchemy documentation to understand why. Thanks again.

Comment: Weird. Surely the tData declaration itself is setting the column name (see my edited version above), so the column should match in the next section by the time you try to update the value. But, as I said, I haven't tested it. Good luck!